# Finding the percentage overlap between a vector file and GPS points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, overlapping-features

I am trying to find a way to find the percentage overlap between a vector polygon map and GPS points.

The purpose of this is to understand area usage of the animal as well as resource selection.

The points are gathered over 2 weeks and the GPS sends a signal every 2minutes when active.

My vector file is an area map that shows different area types that are of interest to my assignment. What I want is to have a table showing percentage of area used highest to lowest based on point location, together with my map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Intersect points with polygon layer to transfer area type to each point
2. Statistics by category with `Field with categories` area type and timestamp. Now you have a table like (my area type is "kategori_2"):
   [image]
3. Statistics by category again on your stat table with `Field with categories` area type
4. Field Calculate a percentage column:
   [image]

Comment: Hey, i this worked thank you for the help. Only had some geometry errors but i fixed that. Highly appriciated